# Android App for recording points of interest

Tags: gratis, android, geo-location

I want to have an app where I can record points of interest with a timestamp. I imagine it like this:

1. I start the app
2. I click on "record this point". The app opens a dialogue where I can enter a name.
3. I click on "Save". Now the app records the geo-location, the current time and the name.
4. I stop the app.

I do this a couple of times. Later, I need an export option. I want to get the data outside of the app.

Please note that I don't want continuous recording. I will hike for ~3 weeks and rarely have electricity. Hence continuous recording is not wanted.

Comment: Maybe some [location-based notes](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_locationmemos) app would fit those needs? I haven't tried any, so I don't have a specific recommendation. Maybe [My favorite places](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.gabm.fancyplaces/) (which unfortunately hasn't seen any update lately)?