# Looking for a simple app to log photos for a beach-combing business

Tags: ios, photography, data, geo-location, inspection

I'm looking for recommendations for software applications, or appropriate search keywords I should be using or other advice to identify a software solution for the following business requirement:

- Operators on small boats go out daily to search for and retrieve cut logs on the open water or washed up on beaches.
- Operators need to record the number of logs retrieved and their type as well as the tie-up point they towed them to
- Ideally, they should also capture a photo of the log and record its GPS location for audit and business analysis purposes
- Obviously, given the environment, the app needs to be simple and convenient to use in bad weather (simple touch-screen button operation).
- Maybe also some safety features such as real-time location transmission.
- Works on iOS.

I suspect there are many existing apps which could be used for this but it's hard to know how to find the perfect fit and to filter the many results that come up.  Ideally I would like to trial no more than two or three candidates.

I tried using the following search terms:

- iPhone app, mobile, business app, field inspection, quality control, geo-tagging, photo logging

Any specific recommendations or more general advice on how to select the right software would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you probably need to search for an IoS app with these keywords: "Points of Interest", Notes, Photos, etc. Here are old related android answers to give you some pointers on what to search for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/52963/android-app-for-recording-points-of-interest    https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/9865/take-gps-coordinatespicturesmemo-of-a-point-of-interest-on-offline-android/9890#9890

Comment: Also check to see if any of these apps exist on IoS https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_locationmemos